# ¿Cómo crear una página de videos?

Tags: php, mysqli, php5

Estoy planteando el diseño de la base de datos llamada **tutoriales**:

```
id       title       autor      detalle          índice       url
 1      HTML 5       Jose    texto content  lista de vídeos   m-m
 2       CSS 3       Jose    texto content  lista de vídeos   m-v
```

La estructura parece ser sencilla, clara y fácil, pero el problema mayor se basa en el índice de los videos.

> En el índice contará toda la lista de los videos.

Aquí el detalle, el problema es que deseo mostrar los primeros *10 videos* de la lista del **índice** y el resto de los vídeos restringirlos, es decir, que se muestren igual pero que el enlace del video esté disponible solamente si se registra en la página web.

Por ejemplo, la consulta de los resultados los asignaría de está manera:

```
while ($video = mysqli_fetch_array($rows)) {
  echo '<div>'.$video['title'].'</div>
        <div>'.$video['autor'].'</div>
        <div>'.$video['detalle'].'</div>
        <div>'.$video['indice'].'</div>';
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  $title = $row['title'];
  $autor = $row['autor'];
  $detalle = $row['detalle'];
  $indice = $row['indice'];
  $urls = $row['url'];
}
```

El problema es, ¿Cómo restringir el resto de videos? ¿Cómo mostrar la lista de los índices de videos a una restricción a cierto número de videos?

Comment: ¿Podrías replantear mejor la pregunta?, pues no se entiende nada de lo que quieres hacer. Si quieres un diseño bien hecho... ¿ves que el autor `José` se repite una y otra vez. Y se seguirá repitiendo cuando tengas millones de registros. Significa que tienes que sacar al autor de ahí, en una tabla llamada `autores` para evitar una tabla enorme y difícil de mantener. Si por lo que he entendido en `indice` iría una lista de vídeos, ocurre lo mismo que con autor... los vídeos deberían existir como entidades independientes en la BD y luego mediante una tabla de relaciones los puedes agrupar.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano he editado mi pregunta no se como más replantearla para que sea claramente, sobre el autor sería algo como un perfil de quien es el autor del vídeo pero crees poder ayudarme tal como lo planteas en su comentario.

Comment: Creo que tienes un problema en el planteamiento al pesar los vídeos como una _lista_. ¿No sería mejor pensar cada vídeo como lo que es, es decir, un vídeo en sí? Luego puedes evaluar si el usuario no está registrado. Si no lo está traes sólo 10 vídeos usando por ejemplo `SELECT ... FROM videos WHERE ... LIMIT 10` y muestras esos 10 vídeos. Si está registrado traes todos los vídeos y los muestras.

Comment: @A.Cedano SI ESE ES MI PROBLEMA LA IDEA ES COMO LA SIGUIENTE IMAGEN [imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcDBz.png) los resultados lo podría mostrar sin problema como el código de ejemplo pero no es correcto no es la forma correcta... Me ayudarías con un pequeño ejemplo.

Comment: @A.Cedano solo un ejemplo sencillo puedes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien, te mostraré un ejemplo de lo que te he dicho en mi comentario.

Te toca a ti refinar los detalles. Tendrás un ejemplo de cómo funciona. He comentado algunas cosas en el código, menos de lo que quisiera, por falta de tiempo. No obstante, creo que el código es bastante claro.

La idea es esta:

Dependiendo de si el usuario está registrado o no, previa verificación en la tabla de usuarios, lanzarás una consulta con `LIMIT 10` o no.

En ambos casos recuperas un array de resultados y construyes una tabla, la cual mostrarás en pantalla. La misma tendrá sólo 10 vídeos si el usuario no está registrado, y todos los vídeos si lo está.

Para consultar a la Base de datos he usado PDO en vez de MySQLi por varios motivos que no quiero exponer ahora, entre ellos porque es más fácil y porque para obtener un arreglo asociativo de resultados, en tu máquina puede fallar si no tienes la extensión mysqlnd instalada... por eso uso PDO. Si por algún motivo estás obligado a usar MySQLi, puedes adaptar esa parte a MySQLi sin mayor problema.

Este es un ejemplo completo en phpfiddle:

#### `Código`: [`Ver Demo`](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/siwp-53q9)

```
<?php

require "util/public_db_info.php";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user_name, $pass_word);

/**
 *  Prueba con un usuario registrado 
 *  En el código  se usa  PDO y  consultas preparadas
*/

$sql = "SELECT usuario_estatus FROM usuario WHERE usuario_id=:id";  
$id=2;
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue("id",$id);
$stmt ->execute();

$bolRegistrado=$stmt->fetchColumn();
imprimir ($bolRegistrado, $pdo);

/**
 *  Prueba con un usuario NO registrado 
 *  En el código  se usa  PDO y  consultas preparadas
*/

$sql = "SELECT usuario_estatus FROM usuario WHERE usuario_id=:id";  
$id=1;
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue("id",$id);
$stmt ->execute();

$bolRegistrado=$stmt->fetchColumn();
imprimir ($bolRegistrado, $pdo);



$pdo = null;


function imprimir($bolRegistrado, $pdo)
{
    if ($bolRegistrado||$bolRegistrado=0)
    {
        $sql_videos="SELECT v.video_id, v.video_titulo, v.video_detalle, a.autor_nombre
                 FROM videos v
                 INNER JOIN autores a ON v.autor_id = a.autor_id";
    }else{
        $sql_videos="SELECT v.video_id, v.video_titulo, v.video_detalle, a.autor_nombre
                 FROM videos v
                 INNER JOIN autores a ON v.autor_id = a.autor_id
                 LIMIT 10";

    }

    $datos=$pdo->query($sql_videos);
    $arrDatos = $datos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($arrDatos)
    {
        echo "<hr />SE ENCONTRARON  ".count($arrDatos). " REGISTROS<br /><hr />";
        /**
         *  Construímos nuestra tabla  de forma limpia
        */
        $strHtml='LISTA DE VÍDEOS:<br />';
        $strHtml.='<table style="border:1px solid black; collapse:collapse;">';
        $strHtml.='<thead>';
        $strHtml.='<tr>';
        $strHtml.='<th>ID</th><th>TÍTULO</th><th>AUTOR</th><th>DESCRIPCION</th>';
        $strHtml.='</th></tr>';
        $strHtml.='<thead>';
        $strHtml.='<tbody>';


        foreach ($arrDatos as $row)
        {
            $strHtml.='<tr>';
            $strHtml.='<td>'.$row["video_id"].'</td>';
            $strHtml.='<td>'.$row["video_titulo"].'</td>';
            $strHtml.='<td>'.$row["autor_nombre"].'</td>';
            $strHtml.='<td>'.$row["video_detalle"].'</td>';
            $strHtml.='</tr>';
        }
        $strHtml.='</tbody>';
        $strHtml.='</table>';
        echo $strHtml;
    }
    else
    {
       echo "No hay datos";
    }
}

?>
```

#### `Resultado`

```html
<hr />SE ENCONTRARON 12 REGISTROS<br />
<hr />LISTA DE VÍDEOS:<br />
<table style="border:1px solid black; collapse:collapse;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>TÍTULO</th>
      <th>AUTOR</th>
      <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>HTML5</td>
          <td>Pedro</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre HTML5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>PHP</td>
          <td>Santiago</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre PHP</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Java</td>
          <td>Juan</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre Java</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>CSS</td>
          <td>Juan</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>JS</td>
          <td>Santiago</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre JS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>Python</td>
          <td>Pedro</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre Py</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>SSH</td>
          <td>Pedro</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre SSH</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>iOS</td>
          <td>Santiago</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre iOS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>Android</td>
          <td>Juan</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre Android</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>Nada</td>
          <td>Santiago</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre Nada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>C#</td>
          <td>Pedro</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre C#</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>Pascal</td>
          <td>Juan</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre Pascal</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
<hr />SE ENCONTRARON 10 REGISTROS<br />
<hr />LISTA DE VÍDEOS:<br />
<table style="border:1px solid black; collapse:collapse;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>TÍTULO</th>
      <th>AUTOR</th>
      <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>HTML5</td>
          <td>Pedro</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre HTML5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>PHP</td>
          <td>Santiago</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre PHP</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Java</td>
          <td>Juan</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre Java</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>CSS</td>
          <td>Juan</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>JS</td>
          <td>Santiago</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre JS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>Python</td>
          <td>Pedro</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre Py</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>SSH</td>
          <td>Pedro</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre SSH</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>iOS</td>
          <td>Santiago</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre iOS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>Android</td>
          <td>Juan</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre Android</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>Nada</td>
          <td>Santiago</td>
          <td>Este vídeo es sobre Nada</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

---

#### `Código de creación de tablas:` [`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/ZKOJL51888)

Este sería un demo de la creación de las tablas. Es también básico. Si usas InnoDB debes tomar en cuenta la declaración de llaves foráneas, la integridad referencial, etc. No lo he hecho por falta de tiempo, como ves, es mucho código. Y también es bueno no dar el trabajo totalmente hecho :)

He implementando algunas de las cosas que te dije en el comentario, como no poner el nombre del autor en la tabla vídeos, sino en una tabla aparte. Luego, mediante `JOIN` se pueden unir las tablas usando las llaves foráneas para traer los datos que necesites.

```
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS videos 
    (
      video_id          INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      video_titulo      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      video_detalle     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      autor_id          INT

    );


INSERT INTO videos (video_id,video_titulo, video_detalle, autor_id) VALUES  
    (1,'HTML5', 'Este vídeo es sobre HTML5',1), 
    (2,'PHP', 'Este vídeo es sobre PHP',2), 
    (3,'Java', 'Este vídeo es sobre Java',3), 
    (4,'CSS', 'Este vídeo es sobre CSS',3), 
    (5,'JS', 'Este vídeo es sobre JS',2), 
    (6,'Python', 'Este vídeo es sobre Py',1), 
    (7,'SSH', 'Este vídeo es sobre SSH',1), 
    (8,'iOS', 'Este vídeo es sobre iOS',2), 
    (9,'Android', 'Este vídeo es sobre Android',3), 
    (10,'Nada', 'Este vídeo es sobre Nada',2), 
    (11,'C#', 'Este vídeo es sobre C#',1), 
    (12,'Pascal', 'Este vídeo es sobre Pascal',3) 

    ; 


CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS autores 
    (
      autor_id          INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      autor_nombre      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL

    );


INSERT INTO autores (autor_id,autor_nombre) VALUES 
    (1,'Pedro'),
    (2,'Santiago'),
    (3,'Juan')
    ;


CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS usuario 
    (
      usuario_id          INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      usuario_nombre      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      usuario_estatus     BOOLEAN  

    );


INSERT INTO usuario (usuario_id,usuario_nombre,usuario_estatus) VALUES 
    (1,'Usuario No Registrado',FALSE),
    (2,'Usuario Registrado',TRUE)
    ;

-- Seleccionado sólo 10
SELECT v.video_id, v.video_titulo, v.video_detalle, a.autor_nombre
FROM videos v
INNER JOIN autores a ON v.autor_id = a.autor_id
LIMIT 10;

-- Seleccionado todos
SELECT v.video_id, v.video_titulo, v.video_detalle, a.autor_nombre
FROM videos v
INNER JOIN autores a ON v.autor_id = a.autor_id;
```